# display a periodic date in 1 month dart language

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I display a periodic date in 1 month, for example, I want a date that appears every 2 days, for example starting from Month 04-2020

```
  2020-04-01 
  2020-04-03 
  2020-04-06
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
var date = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(200000); // initial date

for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++) { 
   var dateCopy = date;
   dateCopy = dateCopy.add(Duration(days: i * 2));
   print(dateCopy);
}
```